# Configuration of options from IConfigurationRoot not working?

Tags: asp.net-core-1.0

The following code is snipped from the examples at [docs.asp.net](https://docs.asp.net/en/1.0.0-rc2/fundamentals/configuration.html).

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Setup options with DI
    services.AddOptions();

    // Configure MyOptions using config
    services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);

    // Configure MyOptions using code
    services.Configure<MyOptions>(myOptions =>
    {
        myOptions.Option1 = "value1_from_action";
    });
```

The call to `services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);`
causes a compilation error:

> cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationRoot' to 'System.Action'

Manually setting up the options works fine. Am I missing something really obvious here?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found out you need to add this extension to your project :

Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions

Comment: More specifically, as a dependency in the project.json

Comment: Worked for me too.

Answer (score 11):

You need to add the following nuget package to your ASP Core Project if you want to configure the strongly typed config in that way.

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions
```

The extension methods contained in the package will allow you to configure the strongly typed configuration the way you want to and the way most tutorials show.

```
services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);
```

**Alternatively**, you could add another binder package:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
```

Configuration would then look something like this:

```
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<MyOptions>(x => Configuration.Bind(x));
```

This is the downside of having so many modular packaged up extensions. It gets easy to lose track of where functionality exists.